# When large number of records in Database,it throws error "Operation has been cancelled by the user" in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, db2

I want to retrieve records from DB2 and display the records in DataGridView in VB.net. If number of records is less it works fine.

But if the database tabe has large number of records it throws error "Operation has been cancelled by the user".
Can any one help please me...

My code is

```
    Dim strSQL As String

    Dim myConn, myCommand, rs As Object

    DataGridView1.DataSource = Nothing
    rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    Const DB_CONNECT_STRING = "Provider=MSDASQL.1;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=cpa5k;Data Source=NP1;DSN=NP1;UID=user;PASSWORD=pass;SDSN=Default;HST=sysplex.com;PRT=4101;Initial Catalog=QA1MM;"
    myConn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    myCommand = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
    myConn.Open(DB_CONNECT_STRING)
    myCommand.ActiveConnection = myConn
    strSQL = " query "
    rs.Open(strSQL, myConn)
    Dim myDA As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim myDS As DataSet = New DataSet
    myDA.Fill(myDS, rs, "MyTable")
    DataGridView1.DataSource = myDS.Tables(0)
    DataGridView1.Refresh()
    myConn.Close()
```

The Error message displayed is:

> See the end of this message for details on invoking  just-in-time
>   (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.
>
> ******* *Exception Text* ********* System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800A0E80): Operation
>   has been cancelled by the user.
>
> at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.LateBinding.InternalLateCall(Object
>   o, Type objType, String name, Object[] args, String[] paramnames,
>   Boolean[] CopyBack, Boolean IgnoreReturn)
>   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.NewLateBinding.LateCall(Object
>   Instance, Type Type, String MemberName, Object[] Arguments, String[]
>   ArgumentNames, Type[] TypeArguments, Boolean[] CopyBack, Boolean
>   IgnoreReturn)    at WindowsApplication2.Form1.Button4_Click(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons
>   button, Int32 clicks)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message&
>   m)    at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32
>   msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)

The query which i am running is :

```
SELECT   A.MVNDR_NBR                     
       ,A.MER_DEPT_NBR                  
      ,C.BYO_NBR                       
      ,B.MKT_NBR                       
      ,D.SKU_NBR                       
        ,A.STR_NBR                       
        ,B.BU_ID                         
        ,COALESCE(D.MIN_EFF_OH_QTY,0)    
        ,COALESCE(D.TRGT_OH_QTY,0)       
        ,D.THRH_BUOM_QTY_PCT             
        ,COALESCE(E.OH_QTY,0)            
        ,COALESCE(E.CHG_OH_QTY,0)        
        ,COALESCE(E.OO_QTY,0)            
        ,E.SKU_VLCTY_CD                  
        ,D.LEAD_TM_DAYS                  
        ,D.REV_TM_DAYS_CNT               
        ,COALESCE(D.SFTY_STK_DAYS,0)     
         ,D.ADJ_ASW_QTY                      
         ,D.MAX_INV_QTY                      
         ,D.TOT_PLNG_OVRD_DAYS               
         ,COALESCE(D.MIN_OH_QTY_DAYS,0)      
         ,F.CURR_DSVC_TYP_CD                 
         ,G.CURR_RMETH_CD                    
         ,F.DCHNL_DC_NBR                     
         ,COALESCE(F.BUY_MIN_QTY,0)          
         ,F.BUY_UOM_QTY                      
         ,COALESCE(E.CORD_ALLOC_QTY,0)       
         ,COALESCE(E.CORD_RSVD_QTY,0)          FROM     PO_AUTO_HORD_STRMV A               
         ,STR                B               
         ,MKT                C               
         ,MVNDR_SKU_STR      F               
         ,SKU_STR_LIST       G                
        ,PO_AUTO_HORD_PARM  D                   LEFT     OUTER JOIN                            
         STRSK_OH_EOO       E                   ON       E.STR_NBR        = D.STR_NBR           AND      E.SKU_NBR        = D.SKU_NBR           WHERE    A.PO_WK_DAY_NBR  = 4   AND      A.EFF_BGN_DT    <= '2011-09-22' AND      A.EFF_END_DT     > '2011-09-22'        AND      D.STR_NBR        = A.STR_NBR           AND      D.MVNDR_NBR      = A.MVNDR_NBR         AND      D.MER_DEPT_NBR   = A.MER_DEPT_NBR      AND      B.STR_NBR        = A.STR_NBR           AND      B.STR_OPEN_DT <= '2011-09-22'       AND      C.MKT_NBR        = B.MKT_NBR           AND      F.MVNDR_NBR      = A.MVNDR_NBR         AND      F.MER_DEPT_NBR   = A.MER_DEPT_NBR      AND      F.SKU_NBR        = D.SKU_NBR            AND      F.STR_NBR        = D.STR_NBR            AND      G.SKU_NBR        = D.SKU_NBR            AND      G.STR_NBR   
= D.STR_NBR            AND      F.OK_TO_ORD_FLG  = 'Y'                  AND      G.SKU_STAT_CD IN (100, 200)             AND      G.SOS_IND    IN ('V','B')           AND      F.CURR_DSVC_TYP_CD IN (1, 3)           ORDER BY A.MVNDR_NBR                            
        ,C.BYO_NBR                              
        ,B.MKT_NBR                              
        ,F.DCHNL_DC_NBR                         
        ,F.CURR_DSVC_TYP_CD                     
        ,D.SKU_NBR                              
        ,A.STR_NBR                               WITH  UR
```

Comment: What happens if you run the query directly in the DB platform (instead of through code). Does it work? If not, you need to fix the query first.

Comment: If i directly run thru the DB platform..it is working...Query is correct only....

Comment: What line is throwing the error?

Comment: I have updated the error in the question....Its giving error in "rs.Open(strSQL, myConn)" line

Comment: Is there any other way to load records from database into DataGridView...Please help me....

Comment: I don't know VB.Net, so I can't really help you there.  However, it might be informative to see the query you are running.

Comment: Why are you using COM ADODB in VB.NET instead of the objects in the System.Data.OleDb namespace?

Comment: I have updated the query in the question...I will try with System.Data.OleDb namespace..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We've had this issue once before, and the work-around is to increase the QUERYTIMEOUTINTERVAL setting (or set to zero - which may make other trouble of its own) in the DB2 Client configuration.

(See http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/message.jspa?messageID=13894231 )

---

BTW, HardCode is right, there really is no reason to use ADODB (especially via CreateObject and late binding!) when .NET provides (the superior, IMO) ADO.NET and OLEDB.